# How to calculate circle button cr , cx SVG?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to build a round slider with svg and javascript.
You can see my code https://codepen.io/jrSakizci/pen/GBrxeo over there.

HTML Code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
<path class="grey" d="M40,90
         A40,40 0 1,1 60,90"
      style="fill:none;"/>
<path class="purple" d="M40,90
         A40,40 0 1,1 60,90"
      style="fill:none;"/>
```

I am stuck with the difficult part but i just want to learn how can i move this circle on this round shape. I am not good at mathematics but maybe there is a function to do it, or maybe even css trick. i literally do research as much as i can do, all links are purple in Google right now.

Any help would be very appericated.

Comment: to move where and how?

Comment: by the way I think this is what you need : https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html .. you need to understand how to go from cartesian to polar coordinates

Comment: @TemaniAfif - moving through circle. think about its range slider.

Comment: Yes that what I understood and the above link is what you need

Comment: Thank you so much, this source is exactly what i need. <3